# Trouble comparing two PHP variables

Tags: php, datetime, variables, compare

this may seem like a stupid question, but it is stumping me nontheless. I'm sure that the answer is something small. I think it's just one of those situations where I have been looking at the code for too long.

I am trying to compare two PHP variables to see if they are the same. As you can see below, I am comparing `$verification_answer` with `strrev(date("Ymd"))` which is today's date, reversed. So today, `$verification_answer` would be 31700102. Every time I try to do the comparison, however, the if statement executes (as a non-match).

```
$verification_answer = strrev(date("Ymd"));

if($verification != $verification_answer){
     $failed .= "<h2>Attention:</h2><p>The verification code is incorrect. Please try again.</p>"; 
}
```

Can anyone see the issue? Thanks!

---

UPDATE: `$verification` is from HTML user input:

```
$verification = mysql_escape_string($_POST['verification']);
```

Comment: Please post what $verification is.

Comment: what is the value of `$verification`? Where does it come from?

Comment: $verification is from HTML user input. I have ensured (by echo()) that after the form is submitted, both $verification and $verification_answer display as the same values

Comment: Note that mysql_escape_string() has been deprecated since php 4.3.0. You should be using mysql_real_escape_string() instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: Try `var_dump` instead of `echo`. It's hard to see differences in whitespace with echo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the `if` statement. Display the two values and you should see some sort of difference:

```
var_dump($verification);
var_dump($verification_answer);
```

Perhaps `$verification` doesn't contain what you think it does, or you misspelled it earlier and assigned to a different variable, or...

Answer (score 3):

> I am comparing $verification_answer with strrev(date("Ymd"))

If that's actually what you intended to do, I think you messed up the name of the variable in the first line; it should be:

```
$verification = strrev(date("Ymd"));
```

If you accidentally overwrote the value of `$verification_answer` and used `$verification` in a comparison when it's undefined, the comparison will always be false. PHP will emit a warning, but if you have them disabled you won't see it

Comment: Woops, that was just a typo while typing the post.

Answer (score 0):

I must have spelled verification wrong somewhere...I copy and pasted 'verification' over each existing variable name and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you turn on warnings in `php.ini` while you're developing it'll help avoid this sort of thing